# htaccess hotlinking and folder redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a problem to prevent hotlinking, let me explain.

i would like to redirect any image file that is  in the folder (up) to a picture url (http://www.domain.com/picture.jpg)

however if the picture file request cam from my website (domain.com) it shows another picture (http://www.domain.com/picture-2.jpg)

is it possible to do so using Htaccess ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the referer-header to determine what image to show. Please note that some users may use privacy-tools that hide the referer header to the server. When they do that, hopefully they will blank the field as opposed to filling it with garbage. For this reason you should load picture.jpg for both an empty referer and one containing domain.com, so that the correct image is always shown on your website. It might load the wrong image on a different website, but that is less of a concern.

Say you link to `http://www.domain.com/picture.jpg` in your html page. You then use the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(domain\.com|^$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-2\.jpg
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ $1-2.jpg [L]
```

---

Depending on what exactly you want to do, for example displaying a footer with copyright information, you can use a different approach where that footer is in the image regardless of the site, but the footer is cropped out on your site. The pros of this approach is that you only have 1 version of the image, and it is always displayed correctly on your site. The con of this solution is that if the hotlinking website is smart, they will crop out that footer as well. In the example below we have a 200x200px image. Only the top half is visible:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px 200px 100px 0px);
}
```

On jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myz8gq1f/

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry but i don't understand what you tried to show, i have a folder which was an upload center before  named (up) and now it does not contain any file, since there is a lot of websites hotlinking to images uploaded before on that center and they are eating my bandwith, i would like to show a picture (nothotlink.jpg) on all those websites however if the old pictures in the same folder is called from my own website (domain.com) it should show a 1x1 px picture .

Comment: The first thing is what you requested. The second thing is a different approach, which is not helpful in your case.